# Compile error when assigning worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a worksheet name to a worksheet after the last worksheet. But, I keep getting a Compile error :Syntax error This is the code at which the compiler says it has a problem. The exact line is the line at which worksheet is being added.

```
logic = "S_ANY"
allowClear = "NO"
arrayIndex = 0
flowName = flow
flowSplit = Split(flowName, "_")
flowNameSuffix = flowSplit(0)
newWorkSheetName = "Test_Master_" & flowNameSuffix
Set ws = Workbooks.Open(pathToFile).Worksheets("Test_Master")
Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open(pathToXl)
ws2.Sheets.Add(After:=ws2.Sheets.Count)).Name = newWorkSheetName
```

ws2 is defined as a Workbook and newWorkSheetName is a String. before this code is only variable declarations. I am not sure as to what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
With ws2.Sheets.Add(After:=ws2.Sheets(ws2.Sheets.Count))
    .Name = "XYZ"
End With
```

copy this:

```
    Set ws = Workbooks.Open(pathToFile).Worksheets("Test_Master")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open(pathToXl)
    With ws2.Sheets.Add(After:=ws2.Sheets(ws2.Sheets.Count))
        .Name = newWorkSheetName
    End With
```

If it still raises an error - uncomment the With-Block and see if your macro works then.

"After:="  excpects the actual Sheet-Objekt.

BR

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this. Now the compiler says. "Compile Error : Expected: End of Statement". Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Please post a little bit more code. (Guess there's maybe a typo or syntax error arround)

Comment: Hey, I added more code as you asked. Everything above the code is just variable declarations.

Comment: Thank you! The error that I was getting is now solved. Although I am getting a different error now. I guess, we cannot open two workbooks at a time and manipulate one of them